# Help in this proof (easy)

Tags: abstract-algebra

**DEFINITION**

Over any commutative ring $A$, for two column vectors $f,g$ we write $f\sim g$ over $A$ to mean that there exists $M\in GL_n(A)$ such that $f=Mg$.

Saying that I have a little doubt in this proof (I'm sure I'm forgetting something and this should be very simple):

[image]

Why $\det M(x)$ is constant in $S^{-1}R$?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $M\in \mathrm{GL}_n(S^{-1}R[x])$ is invertible so $\det(M)$ belongs to the group of units of $S^{-1}R[x]$. It remains to see that these elements are in $S^{-1}R$, i.e. are "constant". As $x$ is an independent variable, you can write $A=S^{-1}R$ and think of $S^{-1}R[x]=A[x]$ as a polynomial ring over $A$.

If $A$ is an integral domain and if $P,Q\in A[x]$ are two polynomials such that $PQ=1$, then both $P$ and $Q$ have to be in $A$. Indeed, if $P$ is of degree $m$ and $Q$ is of degree $n$ then $PQ$ is of degree $m+n$. Since $1$ is of degree $0$, you get that both $P$ and $Q$ are constants.

Comment: The problem is I don't think A is necessarily an integral domain

Comment: Maybe he made a mistake, I think maybe he wanted to say $R$ instead of $S^{-1}R$, what do you think?

Comment: In the hypothesis, $R$ is a entire ring, which means "integral domain". So $S^{-1}R$ natural embedds into the field of fractions of $R$, and then is an integral domain too. So is $A=S^{-1}R[x]$.

Comment: yes, you're right, thank you for your help

Comment: Just one last question: do you know where does he uses the facts: in the beginning: "$M(x)^{-1}f(x)$ is invariant under translation" and "Then $G(x,cy)$ has coefficient in $R$". It seems we don't need these facts to prove the theorem.

Comment: The fact that is is invariant under translation means $M(x)^{-1}f(x)=M(x+y)^{-1}f(x+y)$, that corresponds exactly to $G(x,y)f(x,y)=f(x)$.

Comment: And for "Then $G(x,cy)$ has coefficient in $R$", you want an equivalent over $R[x,y]$ so you dont want to have coefficients in $S^{-1}R[x,y]$.

Comment: Regarding the first question, I did in this way: $G(x,y)f(x+y)=\big(M(x)M(x+y)^{-1}\big)\big(M(x+y)f(0)\big)=M(x)f(0)=f(x)$ I think I didn't use the fact the author mentioned, I just used the definitions.

Comment: Yes, this also works if you prefer.